# WIN32GUI menu bar not rendering when text input window is added

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi, win32gui

**Synopsis**

The GUI menu bar instantiated using `AppendMenu` disappears when `CreateWindowW` is called in the line below.

```
CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"...", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 200, 152, 100, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

This call to `CreateWindowW` creates a text input box.

The following two images show the GUI window with (1) and without (2) the above line of code commented out.

GUI without offending CreateWindowW call:
[image: GUI without offending CreateWindowW call]

GUI with offending CreateWindowW call:
[image: GUI with offending CreateWindowW call]

**Code**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sal.h>



constexpr auto FILE_DROPDOWN_ID = 1;
constexpr auto HELP_POPUP_ID = 2;
constexpr auto LOAD_DROPDOWN_ID = 3;
constexpr auto LOAD_TSD_NO_OFFSET = 4;
constexpr auto FILE_MENU_EXIT = 5;
constexpr auto CHANGE_TITLE = 6;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void AddMenus(HWND);
void AddControls(HWND);
void AddMenusAndControls(HWND);

HMENU hMenu;

//int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow) {
int WINAPI WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd) {
    
    //MessageBox(NULL, L"Upconverter Start up", L"Please load your file", MB_OK);

    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW; // Define window background
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc)) // Pass as reference because arg is type pointer
        return -1;

    CreateWindowW(L"myWindowClass", L"My Window Name", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 200, 500, 500,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Event driven loop

    MSG msg = { 0 }; 


    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }


    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND: // Triggered for every button or menu item. Tells us that something has been clicked. 

        switch (wp)  // This switch statement governs the resultant behavior of a button press on the main window. 
        {
        //case FILE_DROPDOWN_ID:
            //MessageBeep(MB_DEFBUTTON1);
        case HELP_POPUP_ID:
            MessageBeep(MB_DEFBUTTON2);
        case FILE_MENU_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        case LOAD_DROPDOWN_ID:
            MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
        case CHANGE_TITLE:
            
            break;
        }

    case WM_CREATE:
        //AddControls(hWnd);
        //AddMenus(hWnd);
        AddMenusAndControls(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefMDIChildProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
}

void AddMenusAndControls(HWND hWnd) {

    hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hSubMenu = CreateMenu();

    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hFileMenu, L"File");
        AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, LOAD_DROPDOWN_ID, L"New");
        AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hSubMenu, L"Open Submenu");
            AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, CHANGE_TITLE, L"Change Title");
        AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);
        AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, FILE_MENU_EXIT, L"Exit");
    
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, HELP_POPUP_ID, L"Help");
    

    CreateWindowW(L"static", L"Enter text here: ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER, 200, 100, 100, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"...", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 200, 152, 100, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL); // WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL

    SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu);
}

void AddMenus(HWND hWnd) {

    hMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hSubMenu = CreateMenu();

    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, CHANGE_TITLE, L"Change Title");


    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, LOAD_DROPDOWN_ID, L"New");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hSubMenu, L"Open Submenu");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, FILE_MENU_EXIT, L"Exit");

    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hFileMenu, L"File");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, HELP_POPUP_ID, L"Help");


    SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu);

}

void AddControls(HWND hWnd) {
    CreateWindowW(L"static", L"Enter text here: ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER, 200, 100, 100, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"...", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 200, 152, 100, 50, hWnd,
        NULL, NULL, NULL); // WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL
}
```

**Discussion**

I suspect it has to do with the window handle `hWnd` allowing the window contents to be overwritten. So I changed what was previously two passes of `hWnd`

```
    case WM_CREATE:
        AddControls(hWnd);
        AddMenus(hWnd);
```

to a single function call.

```
case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenusAndControls(hWnd);
```

but this had no effect. It also may have to do with `SetMenu` but in what way I'm not sure. I tried moving the `SetMenu` call to different lines in `AddMenusAndControls` which also has no effect.

What is going on here?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Generally when calling `CreateWindow` with `WS_CHILD` and a parent hWnd, you are supposed to provide a child ID.  For sure you need either the child ID or the hWnd returned from CreateWindow for the edit box, otherwise you'll have no way to control it.

Comment: Also, where did you get the idea to call `DefMDIChildProcW` for a window that isn't an MDI child?

Comment: I got it to work by adding a break statement to every case in `WIndowProcedure`. However, I don't know what you're referring to by the return of `CreateWindow' which is void. What am I missing  here? As for the use of `DefMDIChildProcW`, I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JMQkUOhW1s) and it came from there.

Comment: `CreateWindow` does not return `void`, it returns `HWND`.  I don't know when Microsoft messed up the signature in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww) but if you scroll down, you'll see that there is a section describing the return value: "Returns

Type: `HWND`

If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the new window.

If the function fails, the return value is `NULL`."

Comment: And you can't blame the tutorial for `DefMDIChildProcW` because I see it using `DefWindowProcW`.  However, I strongly recommend you get yourself a better tutorial, because that one does make the failure-to-return mistake.  Youtube videos are in general a terrible way to learn programming, because they support only one type of embedded media: video.  You simply can't have a programming tutorial without source code, proper diagrams, and so on.

Comment: Microsoft's online documentation is garbage these days. If you can get a good book to learn Win32 from you'll be much better off.

Comment: @BenVoigt The problem is that CreateWindowW is a macro, and macros don't have return types. This is a hole in the [metadata parser](https://github.com/microsoft/win32metadata); I'll let the responsible parties know.

Comment: @RaymondChen Macros also don't have parameter types.  That's not the problem; the markdown seems to have [been updated manually](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/commit/fcf1f2bfc74f1cada0ce214a48565729aa0e5a36), the problem is that the correct magic markdown keywords weren't used for the return documentation.  Not that I can find documentation of what those magic keywords are supposed to be...

Comment: I don't know how many times I reported that *all* of the documentation on preprocessor macros is broken. It seems to fall on deaf ears. It was a terrible decision to allow .NET folks to have a say in how best to create and deliver documentation for the native platform API.

Comment: @IInspectable We have reported it many times too. I think Raymond letting the responsible parties know is a waste of time - they know already, they just don't care.

Answer (score 2):

Your window procedure is rather badly broken.  It has a non-void return type, but reaches the end without returning anything along all paths except for `default:`.

The correct structure for a window procedure is to **call the default window procedure *unconditionally* at the end of the function**.  Any message which should not be passed to the default window procedure needs to exit its `case` via `return` (and specify the return value) not `break`.

Change

```
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefMDIChildProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
}
```

to

```
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
}
return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
```

I've also fixed your choice of *which* default window procedure to call, since your WinMain seems to be using this window as a top-level frame, not an MDI child.

Because MDI children automatically migrate their menus to the MDI parent when focus changes, and because you're adding a new child control that is capable of receiving focus (before the frame had it), it's quite likely that the focus-related messages sent to your window changes, and since you dutifully forwarded them on, you got the MDI menu behavior you asked for (even though you don't want it).  Don't use `DefMDIChildProcW` if you don't have MDI!

Comment: Thanks That's helpful but unfortunately the issue persisted after I added `return DefMDIChildProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);` to the end of `case WM_create:`

Comment: @MusilMark: Don't try to fix one case at a time, *any* message reaching the end of the non-void function without a `return` statement is instant undefined behavior.

Comment: It's still displaying the same behavior. But this has given me a good starting point. I'm sure there are other things for me to patch up to reach better behavior. Thanks

Comment: It's working now thanks. To anyone reading this in the future, make sure to add break cases and do not rely on fall through to reach `return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wp, lp)`

Comment: @MusilMark: Fall-through doesn't go to the `default:` block, it goes to whatever is immediately following in the source code.  Your `HELP_POPUP_ID` case was calling `DestroyWindow`!

Comment: @mus Indeed, there isn't even a requirement that the `default` label be the last one. It can be in any position. Always compile with at least [/W4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level) and deal with compiler warnings. Adding `/WX` provides an incentive to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
 switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND: // Triggered for every button or menu item. Tells us that something has been clicked. 

        switch (wp)  // This switch statement governs the resultant behavior of a button press on the main window. 
        {
        //case FILE_DROPDOWN_ID:
            //MessageBeep(MB_DEFBUTTON1);
        case HELP_POPUP_ID:
            MessageBeep(MB_DEFBUTTON2);
        case FILE_MENU_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        case LOAD_DROPDOWN_ID:
            MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
        case CHANGE_TITLE:
            
            break;
        }
        break; ///THIS WAS CAUSING ERROR ADD THIS BREAK;
    case WM_CREATE:
        //AddControls(hWnd);
        //AddMenus(hWnd);
        AddMenusAndControls(hWnd);
        break;
```